# creating a foreign key in sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-key-relationship

i need to create a foreign key to map my tables.
Basically this foreign is a primary key of a table.
but the insert statement is creting an issue.
Its an SQLite database.
the table with the primary key is

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + Main
            + "(ROWID integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL,appln_date VARCHAR,appln_no VARCHAR,rupees VARCHAR,tenure VARCHAR,asset VARCHAR);");
```

the table with the foreign key is

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + Applicant
            + "(AppID integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "app_salutation VARCHAR,app_fname VARCHAR,app_mname VARCHAR,app_lname VARCHAR,app_door VARCHAR,app_street VARCHAR,app_building VARCHAR,app_area VARCHAR,app_post VARCHAR,app_tehsil VARCHAR,app_state VARCHAR,app_landmark VARCHAR,ROWID integer References "+Main+"(ROWID));");
```

the insert statement is

```
openOrCreateDatabase();
    createappinfo();
    String insertString = "insert into " + Applicant
            + " Values(";

    String inString = "";
    for (int i =0; i < data.size(); i++) {

        inString = inString + "\"" + data.get(i) + "\",";

    }

    inString = inString.substring(0, inString.length() - 1);
    int row=db.rawQuery("select * from "+Main+";" ,null).getCount()+1;
    insertString = insertString + row+"," +inString + ");";
    System.out.println("** insert value ** " + insertString);
    db.execSQL(insertString);

    closeDatabase();
```

but this code is generating an error..

```
04-25 11:43:57.422: E/SQLiteLog(17825): (1) table applicanttable has 14 columns but 13 values were supplied
```

Comment: Your error code says that you supply only 13 values instead of 14. Check again that you're providing values for all the columns with `data`

Comment: @Bigood the first is an autoincrement field then 12 columns are filled through the above code and then theres a foreign key...so the first and the last feild values are not to be passed the...wats the error..i can seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You should make on database this statements like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Main" (ROWID integer primary key autoincrement NOT NULL,appln_date VARCHAR,appln_no VARCHAR,rupees VARCHAR,tenure VARCHAR,asset VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Applicant" (AppID integer primary key autoincrement, app_salutation VARCHAR,app_fname VARCHAR,app_mname VARCHAR,app_lname VARCHAR,app_door VARCHAR,app_street VARCHAR,app_building VARCHAR,app_area VARCHAR,app_post VARCHAR,app_tehsil VARCHAR,app_state VARCHAR,app_landmark VARCHAR,ROWID integer References "Main"(ROWID));
insert into "Applicant" Values("11","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l", (SELECT Count(*) +1 FROM main));
```

The values in this example are random.

So if You are 100% sure that this your for statement return properly all values except last one.
Your last argument should look like this:

```
insertString = "ROWID integer References "Main"(ROWID);";
```